# jquery Dollar sign

Tags: jquery, dollar-sign

i have this html:

```
<ul id="list1" class="eventlist">
  <li>plain</li>
  <li class="special">special <button>I am special</button></li>
  <li>plain</li>
</ul>
```

and I have this jquery code:

```
$('#list1 li.special button').click(function(event) {

  var $newLi = $('<li class="special"><button>I am new</button></li>');
  var $tgt = $(event.target);
});
```

My question is what is the difference between

```
var $tgt = $(event.target);
```

and

```
var $tgt = event.target;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`event.target` is a reference to the DOM node.
`$(event.target)` is a jQuery object that wraps the DOM node, which lets you use jQuery's magic to query manipulate the DOM.

In other words, you can do this:

```
$(event.target).addClass('myClass');
```

but you can't do this:

```
event.tagert.addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: Isn't it also a call to a function named `$()` which returns a jQuery object?

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, the local varialbe `$tgt` will hold the jQuery element (wrapped around a DOM element), in the second case it will hold the DOM element.

You cannot use the jQuery manipulation methods (such as `.val()`) directly on DOM elements, hence you need to convert it to a jQuery element first if you want to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise just using `$(this)` to grab the element. jQuery does that internally so you don't have to:

```
$('#list1 li.special button').click(function() {
    var $tgt = $(this);
});
```

To answer your question: `$(event.target)` will be extended with jQuery, and `event.target` won't.

Comment: To clarify, AFAIK the difference between this and event.target in a jQuery event handler is that 'this' is the DOM element you assigned the handler on.  event.target is the element that actually got the event. E.g. if you put a click handler on a div containing other code, the handler will get events where this is the div tag, and event.target is whatever the most-nested tag was that actually got clicked on.

Comment: Not really... If a `click` event is bound to all paragraph tags in a document, for instance, `this` inside the handler will refer to the the single element that was clicked---not all of the paragraphs that the handler was bound to. 

`$('p').click(function(){ /* (this) will will reference the particular paragraph that was clicked */ });`